# Euler cycle in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected graph $G$, $G'$ graph is created, for every edge in $G$ a node is assigned in $G'$ if two edges in $G$ have a common node we add a edge between their nodes in $G'$.

I need to determine if $G$ has an Euler cycle does that mean $G'$ will have one too, and vice versa if $G'$ has a Euler cycle does that mean $G$ must have one?

I tried solving the problem using trial and error, but that did not get me far.

If you have any insight, please share it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete graph on four points has no Euler cycle (because all its vertices have odd degree), but in its line graph (the $G'$ you defined) every node has degree four, so there is an Euler cycle.

The converse implication, on the other hand, is correct.  If every vertex of $G$ has even degree, then so does every vertex of $G'$.  In more detail, the vertex of $G'$ corresponding to an edge $\{u,v\}$ of $G$ has degree (in $G'$) equal to the sum of the degrees (in $G$) of $u$ and $v$ minus $2$.